# Print just git commit sha and a pattern using sed

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep, git

I'm running from the terminal in OSX, and given a git log format like:

```
* 58dbb08 Joe Blogs 5 weeks ago | [ABC-123] Commit message contents 
* 5a9c5e1 Jane Doe 3 weeks ago | Commit Contents with XYZ-987 jira ticket number
* 6070ee0 Some Person 3 weeks ago | Commit which references [MNO-456, MNO-999]
```

I'd like to generate a list in the CLI (using git log, grep, sort, sed) on OSX which would print out the log in such a format:

```
  58dbb08 │ ABC-123
  5a9c5e1 │ XYZ-987
  6070ee0 │ MNO-456, MNO-999
──────────│──────────────────────
   ꜛ sha  │  ꜛ jira tickets
```

The purpose is so our QA can extract a list of Jira Tickets which were referenced inside of git commits, and then easily find the associated commit/ticket by looking through the list

I've got little experience in `sed`and having difficulties understanding the ways of extracting and replacing patterns, then printing only the matched patterns. I've read the docs, but some of the language is unfamiliar considering I rarely touch unix/regex, and I couldn't decipher how to extract multiple patterns and replace un-matched strings.

---

What I'm working with currently;

```
git log --oneline 7.2.0..HEAD | 
    grep -iEo "([a-f0-9]{7})(.*[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,6}-[0-9]{1,4})+" | 
    sort -u | 
    sed -n "s/\([a-zA-Z0-9]\{2,7\}-[0-9]\{1,4\}\)/, \1 /pg"
```

which gets me to;

```
58dbb08 Joe Blogs 5 weeks ago | [, ABC-123
5a9c5e1 Jane Doe 3 weeks ago | Commit Contents with , XYZ-987 
6070ee0 Some Person 3 weeks ago | Commit which references [, MNO-456 , , MNO-999
```

which is close, but I can't get rid of the stuff I don't need

Answer (score 1):

So, I punished my little brain, pushed and came up with *an ugly solution*.

**I don't think it's the best, so I'd still appreciate/accept any help and improvements!**

```
git log 7.2.0..HEAD --oneline | 
    grep -iEo "([a-f0-9]{7})(.*[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,6}-[0-9]{1,4})+" | 
    sort -u | 
    sed -E $'s/([a-f0-9]{7}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,7}-[0-9]{1,4})/ \\\n\\1\\\n/g' | 
    grep -iEo "([a-f0-9]{7}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,6}-[0-9]{1,4})+" | 
    tr '\n' ' ' | 
    sed -E $'s/([a-f0-9]{7})/\\\n\\1 →/g' | 
    sed -E 's/([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,7}-[0-9]{1,4})/\1,/g' | 
    sed -E 's/(..)$//'
```

this command splits the matched expressions across multiple lines using `sed`to insert some `\n`, then it `grep`s the expressions I need, again, and only keeps them. Then finally it goes back and replaces those `\n` with the `→` and `,` characters respectively, then trimming the last `,`.

I end up with:

```
58dbb08 → ABC-123
5a9c5e1 → XYZ-987
6070ee0 → MNO-456, MNO-999
```

I find this to be decently fast on a log size of less than 200 commits... it's purpose is for helping to generate some issue-lists in the release notes, so it shouldn't be much more than that. But again; any speed/quality improvements are well received!

Comment: Most (all?) `sed` versions allow to chain several commands, so you could write e.g. `sed -E -e 's/one/two/g' -e 's/three/four/g'`, to do the replacements in one go. That saves a few command runs. Or you could write the mangling in Perl, that allows you to use more familiar program logic (variables, conditionals, and so on).